# UNION ALL in (vba string variable)

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have this query and its works just fine :

```
SELECT Count(*) AS employ_number, table1.job AS jobs
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT names, job FROM table1)  AS countx
GROUP BY table1.job
UNION ALL SELECT Count(*) AS employ_number, table2.job AS jobs
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT names, job FROM table2)  AS countx
GROUP BY table2.job;
```

now I'm trying to put the above query in vba string variable as the following :

```
sql = "SELECT Count(*) AS employ_number, table1.job AS jobs FROM (SELECT DISTINCT names, job FROM table1) " _
        & "GROUP BY table1.job" _
        & " UNION ALL " _
        & "SELECT Count(*) AS employ_number, table2.job AS jobs FROM (SELECT DISTINCT names, job FROM table2) " _
        & "GROUP BY table2.job"
```

but I got an error " missed operator " ,
however it works fine for one section ,,
how the correct UNION ALL formula in vba ?
NOTE :- there's two tables (table1 , table2) in my database ,
thank you in advance  .

Comment: You're missing the subquery aliases `AS countx`.

Comment: how ? can you please explain it more

Comment: Put a breakpoint after you generate `sql` in your VBA code.  Then type `?sql` in the Immediate Window and compare it to your working query.  You'll see exactly what I mean.

Comment: Or apparently you can watch @ThomasInzina's video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved ..
I uninstalled office 2007 then installed office 2003
and every thing went great
it worked .

Answer (score 1):

You were missing `AS countx`.

Here is how I prepare queries using the Immediate Window

[image]

```
"SELECT Count(*) AS employ_number, table1.job AS jobs " & _
"FROM (SELECT DISTINCT names, job FROM table1)  AS countx " & _
"GROUP BY table1.job " & _
"UNION ALL SELECT Count(*) AS employ_number, table2.job AS jobs " & _
"FROM (SELECT DISTINCT names, job FROM table2)  AS countx " & _
"GROUP BY table2.job; "
```

Comment: Your original query runs?

Comment: sure , it runs very well , by the way i didn't miss the countx , but I forgot to put it in the question

Comment: I doubt it makes a difference, but @ThomasInzina had also added a trailing semi-colon.

Comment: @ThomasInzina throw some `& vbCrLf & _` line endings in, and remove the need for trailing spaces *and* you get pretty output.

Comment: @Howard I built a test database.  Both of your queries compiled.  Could you show the rest of your code?

Comment: ok , I will explain it , I use this  ( sql ) variable as a recordsource for a report , I put the following in the ( on load event ) : -                                     Private Sub Report_Load()
sql = "SELECT Count(*) AS employ_number, table1.job AS jobs " & _
        "FROM (SELECT DISTINCT names, job FROM table1)  AS countx " & _
        "GROUP BY table1.job " & _
        "UNION ALL SELECT Count(*) AS employ_number, table2.job AS jobs " & _
        "FROM (SELECT DISTINCT names, job FROM table2)  AS countx " & _
        "GROUP BY table2.job; "
Me.RecordSource = sql
End Sub

Comment: the stars won't appears inside the braces ' count () '  in the above comment, but they are exists .

Comment: @Howard I created a simple report and both queries worked in the `Report_Load` event.    `AS countx` seems to be a non-factor.  Do you have any controls in the report dependant  on `countx`? Can you provide a download link for the database?  You'll need to use a service like Google Drive, Google Docs, FileHippo or DropBox.

Comment: @ThomasInzina please give me your email to share my db with you

Comment: I have sent it as zip file .

Comment: @Howard I haven't received the file.  GMail can be picky about file types.   Can you send it to my alt email: mr9ball@aol.com ?

Comment: @ThomasInzina did you receive the file ?

Answer (score 0):

You using the countx alias:

```
sql = "SELECT Count(*) AS employ_number, countx.job AS jobs " & _
      "FROM (SELECT DISTINCT names, job FROM table1) AS countx " & _
      "GROUP BY countx.job " & _
      "UNION ALL " & _
      "SELECT Count(*) AS employ_number, countx.job AS jobs " & _
      "FROM (SELECT DISTINCT names, job FROM table2) AS countx " & _
      "GROUP BY countx.job"
```

Comment: I got this error message : - The Microsoft Office Access database engine could not find the object .

Comment: Then you have a misspelled table or field name. The query runs here (with different tables/fields of course).

Comment: every thing is right , nothing missed or misspelled , as I mentioned in my first post when I use only one section it works as expected ,, but I reading a msdn online support they said that such problem could be solved by using ms office 2007 sp1 , because such error could be happen when the union query is much complex .

Comment: OK. It runs in 2016. You really should apply all service packs, indeed for Office 2007 - which now is three versions behind.

Comment: I'll try it then back .

Comment: so the issue would be solved if we just be a bit modern !!? I would like to inform you that the error occurs only in office 2007 and 2010 , and the same project is working perfectly in office 2003 .

Comment: I can't tell for sure, but it might be true.